# Why does the prediction measures like accuracy and F1 does not improve when applied with selected Features?

Tags: r, performance, feature-selection, measure, mlr

I am working on building a model using MLR package by supervised methods. The steps I followed are

1) Cleaned the data
2) Applied feature selection(Correlation based Feature Selection)
3) Did prediction using MLR package

```
library(mlr)
mlr_data <- as.data.frame(scale(df_allF[,res.cfs]))
mlr_data$label <- factor(df_allF$label)

NAN_col <- sapply(mlr_data, function(x) all(is.nan(x)))
mlr_data <- mlr_data[,!NAN_col]

task <- makeClassifTask(data = mlr_data,target = "label")
task <- normalizeFeatures(task,method = "standardize")
lrn = makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob")
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("LOO")
rin = makeResampleInstance(rdesc, task)
#Search for hyperparameters
ps <- makeParamSet(
makeIntegerParam("minsplit",lower = 10, upper = 50),
makeIntegerParam("minbucket", lower = 5, upper = 50),
makeNumericParam("cp", lower = 0.001, upper = 0.2)
)
ctrl1 = makeTuneControlRandom(tune.threshold = TRUE)
lrn1 = tuneParams(lrn, resampling = rdesc,task = task, measures = acc, par.set = ps, control = ctrl1)

rpart.tree <- setHyperPars(lrn, par.vals = lrn1$x)

t.rpart <- train(rpart.tree, task)
getLearnerModel(t.rpart)

tpmodel <- predict(t.rpart, task)

cat("\nConfusion Matrix before setting Threshold:\n ")
calculateConfusionMatrix(tpmodel)

threshold.update <- lrn1$threshold
tpmodel <- setThreshold(tpmodel,threshold.update)

cat("\nConfusion Matrix after setting Threshold:\n ")
calculateConfusionMatrix(tpmodel)


cat("\nMeasures : ")
m1 <- performance(tpmodel, acc)
m2 <- measureF1(tpmodel$data$truth,tpmodel$data$response,"Healthy")

cat("F1 = ",m2,"Accuracy = ",m1)
```

The results of F1 and Accuracy when

**Dataset with all Features**
F1 = 0.923,  Accuracy = 0.928
**Dataset with selected features(CFS)**
F1 = 0.863, Accuracy = 0.857
**Dataset with selected features using Information Gain**
F1 = 0.8947, Accuracy = 0.904

Here, the results are not improving. The whole dataset consist of 154 features and 42 columns.

Do I have a solution or reason for this? I tried most of Feature Selection method.But no improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature selection methods you're using don't use the performance of a classifier to select features. For that, use a [wrapper method](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/feature_selection.html#wrapper-methods) that explicitly takes performance into account. That said, there's no guarantee that feature selection will improve performance.

Comment: Thanks...I will try this once and update the results. :)

Comment: So do u mean that using external algorithms for feature selection doesn't work with mlr package?

Comment: No, it definitely works. It's just not what you're looking for here.

Comment: Since I am beginner with supervised techniques. I would like to know when we basically do feature selection, how do we validate that which features are the best for the model?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by validation. If you're interested in improving performance, like in your case, the wrapper method is the way to go. If you're interested in finding the features that are most important in terms of the underlying problem, it may be the feature selections that ignore the prediction. It depends on the particular case.

Comment: Thanking you, I would like to some help with information, I have mailed you. please help me if its possible.